# Is there an analogue of assertAll for the check method in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, assert

junit has assertAll which allows you to perform all the required checks without throwing an exception for one of them, thereby ignoring the rest. For example:

```
assertAll(
    { assertEquals(a, b) },
    { assertEquals(c, d) },
)
```

Is there an analogue for the Kotlin language to perform several checks?
Something like checkAll, for example:

```
checkAll(
    check(a == b) { "error 1" },
    check(c == d) { "error 2" },
}
```

If both conditions are false, at the output we get:
error 1
error 2

Comment: Is this for unit testing or for use in production code? If it's for unit testing, you can use [Kotest soft assertions](https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/soft-assertions.html) or [Strikt block assertions](https://gist.github.com/jiffle/9ca3db46f40283c06c294079095afa8b#block-assertions) or [AssertK multiple assertions](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/assertk?tab=readme-ov-file#multiple-assertions).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently nothing like this in the Kotlin stdlib, but you can write your own.

A more idiomatic syntax in Kotlin might be to pass a block of checks, like this:

```
checkAll {
    check(a == b) { "error 1" }
    check(c == d) { "error 2" }
}
```

One advantage is that you could, for example, insert some additional code between checks.

You can't use the stdlib version of `check` because it immediately throws an `IllegalStateException`. But you can write `checkAll` so that it provides you with a custom version of `check` inside the block:

```
class CheckAllScope(val messages: MutableList<String>) {
    inline fun check(value: Boolean, lazyMessage: () -> Any) {
        if (!value)
            messages += lazyMessage().toString()
    }
}

fun checkAll(block: CheckAllScope.() -> Unit) {
    val messages = mutableListOf<String>()
    CheckAllScope(messages).block()
    if (messages.isNotEmpty())
        throw IllegalStateException("The following checks have failed: $messages")
}
```

Remember to add overloads to `CheckAllScope` for all the other versions of `check`, such as `checkNotNull`. See the stdlib source for a template of how to do this.

Also, you could do something similar for `require`, by writing a new function `requireAll`.

**Drawback**

If you do such soft assertions, you will lose the advantage of smart casts. For example, using the standard `check` function:

```
check(v != null)
check(v.size > 1)  // No need for v?.size, v is smart-cast to non-null
```

Answer (score -1):

You can construct something pretty simple that does that

```
fun check(checkExpression: Boolean, message: () -> String): Pair<Boolean, () -> String> {
    return Pair(checkExpression, message)
}


fun checkAll(vararg checks: Pair<Boolean, () -> String>): List<String> {
    return checks.filter { !it.first }.map { it.second() }
}
```

so

```
fun main() {
    val a = 1
    val b = 2
    val c = 3
    val d = 4

    val result = checkAll(
        check( a == b ) { "a != b" },
        check( c == d ) { "c != d" },
    )

    // result is list of strings ["a != b", "c != d"]
    println(result)
}
```

will give a list with the strings that don't pass